# Stop image from tiling

Tags: delphi

I have a procedure:

```
 procedure DrawSolidHexImage(Target: TCanvas;     { Canvas to draw hex on }
                         Fillstyle : TBrushStyle; { How to fill the hex }
                         Fillcolor : TColor;      { Color to fill it }
                         fillimage : Tbitmap;     { Image to show}
                         Linestyle : TPenStyle;   { What kind of lines }
                         LineColor : Tcolor;      { What color for lines }
                         x,y,radius: integer;     { Position and size of Hex }
                         button    : boolean);    { Make hexes look like buttons? }
```

When I use this, the image is tiled to fill the area. Is there something I can add or must remove to make it not tile? Thus not repeating the image. Maybe make it center?

```
{Solid Hexagon drawing function}
procedure THexMap.DrawSolidHeximage(Target:TCanvas;
                          Fillstyle : TBrushStyle;
                          Fillcolor : TColor;
                          Fillimage : TBitmap;
                          Linestyle : TPenStyle;
                          LineColor : Tcolor;
                          x,y,radius: integer;
                          button    : boolean);
 var
   p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6:TPoint;
 Begin
   p0 := Point(x,y);

   {compute each point of hex based on center coordinate (p0) }
   p1.x := p0.x - round(Radius /2);
   p1.y := p0.y - Rise;
   p2.x := p0.x + round(Radius /2);
   p2.y := p1.y;
   p3.x := p0.x + Radius;
   p3.y := p0.y;
   p4.x := p2.x;
   p4.y := p0.y + rise;
   p5.x := p1.x;
   p5.y := p4.y;
   p6.x := p0.x - Radius;
   p6.y := p0.y;

   {set color / Style of lines}
   target.pen.color := linecolor;
   target.pen.style := linestyle;

   {Set color and style of hex }
   target.brush.color := FillColor;
   target.brush.style := FillStyle;
   target.Brush.Bitmap := Fillimage;

   {draw the hex}
   target.polygon([p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6]);

   {If Desired, draw the borders for the hex}
   if button = true then
   begin
     with target do
     begin
       pen.mode:=pmcopy;
       pen.color:=clWhite;
       moveto(p5.x+1,p5.y-1);
       lineto(p6.x+1,p6.y);
       lineto(p1.x+1,p1.y+1);
       lineto(p2.x-1,p2.y+1);
       pen.color:=clBlack;
       lineto(p3.x-1,p3.y);
       lineto(p4.x-1,p4.y-1);
       lineto(p5.x+1,p5.y-1);
     end;
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: Can you show in code how the image is drawn in your procedure?

Comment: I suspect `Target.Brush.Bitmap` is set.

Comment: I wonder, are we just meant to guess what the code is? -1 and vote to close as "not a real question". You've asked 18 questions now and you really ought to know what's required to get a good answer.

Comment: it is a good question and maybe you should try to understand something before giving -1 or asking to close something.

Comment: Sorry Glen, but I completely have to agree with David: the question isn't clear. If you don't show us the code of the `DrawSolidHexImage` routine, then we cannot answer why the image is tiled. The code that calls this routine (as you added) isn't relevant. Besides: what means _Hex_? -1

Comment: I dont see whats so confusing?  how do you stop tiles on a canvas? thats all the code i use to put an image on a hex canvas? The procedure is all that should of been needed? as there either is a propery of canvas or there is not one for making an image center?  But what ever i guess close this post

Comment: There are many ways to tile an image, one of them being the code I posted in the second comment. If you don't have the code of `DrawSolidHexImage`, then I think you will not be able to solve this issue, and I'm certain none of us will be able to answer. If you call `B` from `A` while there is a problem with `B`, and you give us `A`, well then what do you expect from us? Again sorry, but my crystal ball is still in backorder.

Comment: @Glen - As you might have guessed by now, there's no 'Tile' or 'Center' property of TCanvas. Your question is not confusing, it just lacks any information as to even guess what might be the problem. Apparently the drawing is carried out by 'DrawSolidHexImage' procedure, but no one knows what's inside the procedure.

Comment: ahh , when i did a search for the procedure it never showed up.. so i thought it was just passing var.. but i found it and updated post..

Comment: I removed the -1 and voted to reopen: the question is now clear and doesn't deserve nor need closure anymore.

Comment: Agreed, original state of the question was unclear, but now I see the issue is a bit different from what was interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, see my second comment: `Target.Brush.Bitmap` is set. Removal of that line will prevent the tiling effect, but will also completely prevent any image from being drawn. To compensate that, use something like:

```
Target.Draw(x, y, FillImage);
```

You may have to fiddle with the coordinates though.

Comment: ok i can see how that would help, but when you say x,y  is that x,y the total of the hex? thus stretching the image?  or do i make x,y the size of the image thus showing one image? will it then center it?  I will give it a try as soon as i get home but figured i would ask :D

Comment: Glen, the `Draw` procedure draws the image at the x,y coordinate you tell it to draw at. Wasn't that clear when you read the documentation? It doesn't automatically center the image. If you want to draw the image at the center of something, then compute the appropriate x,y coordinate and draw your image there. There's no magic here. It doesn't stretch, either — it only takes *x* and *y* parameters, so how could it know how much to stretch? Use `StretchDraw` for that.

Comment: Closed  and -3. Lol. And yes rob it was clear so I asked anyhow

Comment: thanks finally got around to this and it worked with that concept.